# Clip vector layer in QGIS and Python?

Tags: qgis, python, clip

I want to write a Python function to create a shapefile layer from clipping an input layer using a mask.

Does someone know the way how to do it?

Comment: clipping with what? a mask? another shapefile? Current canvas extent? Also please put some effort into it and tell us what you did so far and where you failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", mymask, myresult, myinput], shell=True)

The my***s are all shapefiles.